# Spring Integration http:outbound-gateway "no suitable HttpMessageConverter"

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, spring-integration

We are receiving the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request:
  no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for
  request type [com.company.FileRecord] and
  content type [application/x-java-serialized-object]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:770)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:527)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:472)
...
```

This is being thrown by an `http:outbound-gateway` with a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` attached, like so:

```
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes"
              value="application/x-java-serialized-object"/>
</bean>

<int:transformer input-channel="transformationChannel"
                 output-channel="registrationQueue"
                 ref="fileTransformer"/>

<int:channel id="registrationQueue"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="gateway"
                           request-channel="registrationQueue"
                           message-converters="jsonMessageConverter"
                           url-expression="@urlGenerator.resolve()"
                           http-method="POST"
                           expected-response-type="javax.ws.rs.core.Response"
                           reply-channel="nullChannel"
                           error-handler="httpResponseErrorHandler"/>
```

Out object being serialized is annotated for Jackson serialization:

```
public class FileRecord {

    @JsonProperty
    private final String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String path;

    ...

}
```

I *believe* this was working with Spring Integration 2.2 and started to fail with a migration to 3.0.

It jumps out at me as odd that we are trying to serialize as `application/x-java-serialized-object`. I'd expect `application/json` here. Perhaps a `header-enricher` is called for? If so, I'd like to understand why exactly this needs to expressed. Shouldn't my `jsonMessageConverter` know this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the true cause or fix is, but I found a different approach which does the trick.

First, I removed the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` bean entirely.

I then added an extra transformer to explicitly convert my POJO to JSON:

```
<int:transformer input-channel="objectTransformationChannel"
                 output-channel="jsonTransformationChannel"
                 ref="fileTransformer"/>
<int:channel id="jsonTransformationChannel"/>
<int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="jsonTransformationChannel"
                                output-channel="registrationQueue"/>
<int:channel id="registrationQueue"/>
```

For the `outbound-gateway`, I just needed to remove the `message-converters` as my payload is now JSON.

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="gateway"
                           request-channel="registrationQueue"
                           url-expression="@urlGenerator.resolve()"
                           http-method="POST"
                           expected-response-type="javax.ws.rs.core.Response"
                           reply-channel="nullChannel"
                           error-handler="httpResponseErrorHandler"/>
```

Comment: Yes, that will work too, but filtering out the content-type header should work with your previous config.

Answer (score 0):

??

You are replacing the default supported (json) media types with this...

```
<property name="supportedMediaTypes"
          value="application/x-java-serialized-object"/>
```

...the constructor sets them up properly...

```
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    super(new MediaType("application", "json", DEFAULT_CHARSET),
            new MediaType("application", "*+json", DEFAULT_CHARSET));
}
```

Just remove...

```
<property name="supportedMediaTypes"
          value="application/x-java-serialized-object"/>
```

...and you should be good.

Comment: But doesn't the error message "``content type [application/x-java-serialized-object]``" tell me that my content is of that type?

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry; didn't notice the exception, but the config is definitely wrong. What is upstream of this flow? Is something setting the content type header that way? Maybe post a DEBUG log for your flow someplace. If it's set by something upstream you'll need a header filter to remove it.

Comment: @GaryRussell if I understand your message, and based on my expectations, if no content-type header is explicitly set I would have expected the HTTP outbound gateway to determine the appropriate content type to use as `RestTemplate` does (by querying the configured `MessageConverter`s). However, `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.resolveContentType(Object)` in Spring Integration 4.3 does exactly this: explicitly sets the content type to `application/x-java-serialized-object` for whatever is not a `byte[]`, `Source` or `Map`. So my POJO payloads produce the above exception. Is this expected?

Comment: Please don't comment on 5-year-old answers; ask a new question and show your code/configuration. But, on the face of it, it sounds like a bug.